# Error con conexion pdo

Tags: php, pdo

estoy intentando acceder a la base de datos utilizando la conexión pdo, lo estoy haciendo mediante una clase Model que contiene la conexion y una query que es heredada por la clase User que es la que estoy llamando.
Pero arroja éste error al utilizar el metodo getAll()

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Connection::prepare() in C:\xampp\htdocs\rank-API\app\models\Model.php:17
```

éstas son las clases model y connection, la de user solo sobrescribe el atributo table

clase model:

```
 class Model
{
    protected $table = "default";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $connection;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = Connection::getConnection();    
    }

    public function getAll(){
        try{

            $query = $this->connection->prepare('select * from ' . $this->table);
            $query->execute();

            return $query->fetchAll();

        }catch(PDOException $e){

            echo $e->getMessage();

        }finally{

            $this->connection = null;

        }

    }

}
```

clase connection:

```
    class Connection
{
    private $host = DB_CONFIG['host'];
    private $database = DB_CONFIG['database'];
    private $user = DB_CONFIG['user'];
    private $pass = DB_CONFIG['pass'];

    private static $connection;


    function __construct()
    {
        try{

            $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->database", 
                                    $this->user, 
                                    $this->pass); 
            $connection->exec("set names utf8");
            $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            self::$connection = $connection;


        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {

            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();

            }
    }

    public static function getConnection(){

        if (self::$connection === null) {
            self::$connection = new self();
        }
        return self::$connection;

    }

}
```

Comment: y como vinculas un archivo con otro, o si ambas clases estan en el mismo archivo donde esta el extends?

Comment: el require de connection está en el index.php, y el del model lo hago directo desde el modelo user

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza estos codigos:

Archivo database.php

```
<?php
class Database
{
    public static function StartUp()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=basededatos;charset=utf8', 'usuario', 'contraseña');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
        return $pdo;
    }
}
```

Archivo Model:

```
<?php
require_once 'model/database.php';
class Model
{
    private $pdo;

    public function __CONSTRUCT()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->pdo = Database::StartUp();     
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        try
        {
            $result = array();

            $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla_de_basedatos");
            $stm->execute();

            return $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

El método getAll() te retorna todo los registros que con un foreach puedes listarlos.